# Rails Migration, how to add multiple columns to a table in batch mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, migration, alter-table

When I want to add multiple columns to an existing table I can do this:

```
rails g migration AddColumnsToUser col1:integer col2:integer .. etc.
```

This will generate a migration with several lines:

```
def change
  add_column :users, :col1, :integer
  add_column :users, :col2, :integer
end
```

Which will be translated in several `alter table` commands to the backend DB:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN col1 SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN col2 SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL;
```

The problem is that if you are dealing with a big table, each of these `alter table` will take a lot of time, at less in MySQL, because the backend engine will generate a duplication of the table and will do a lot of expensive processes. And all this work has to be done for each column I want to add.

So, my question, is how can I aggregate all these `add_column` sentences in only one so the result will be an `alter table` in batch mode, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE users
    ADD COLUMN col1 SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
    ADD COLUMN col2 SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use change_table in your migration with the option bulk: true.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_table

Comment: More details in here: https://aaronlasseigne.com/2012/06/05/faster-activerecord-migrations-using-change-table-bulk/

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple statments or custom sql go this way:

```
execute <<-SQL
   ALTER TABLE users
    ADD COLUMN col1 SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
    ADD COLUMN col2 SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL;
SQL
```